# use delegate to change source of img when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a button that will take in a website url and then display stars to collect a website rating. That part works fine. When trying to click on the stars to highlight the clicked and all prev (prevAll) stars and change the source to staron.gif but nothing happens on click. I want to use the delegate function to do this, and then a function. My function is not working.

```
 $('#websiteButton').mousedown(function() {
    var inputSite = prompt("Enter one of your favorite website urls");
    var appendHTML = "<div class=\"webfav\"><a href='"+inputSite+"'>"+inputSite+"</a> <img id=\"s1\" src=\"staroff.gif\"/><img id=\"s2\" src=\"staroff.gif\"/><img id=\"s3\" src=\"staroff.gif\"/><img id=\"s4\" src=\"staroff.gif\"/><img id=\"s5\" src=\"staroff.gif\"/> <br></div>";
    $('#sect2').append(appendHTML);
    });//end of add favorites

$('.webfav').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
 $(img, this).attr('src', 'staron.gif');
 $(img, this).prevAll().attr('src', 'staron.gif');
 });
```

I've also tried just this and this.id

Comment: Try `$(document).on('.webfav img', 'click', function() {`

Comment: `$('.webfav').on('click','img', function() {})`

Comment: @aldrin27 If `<div class=\"webfav\">` is being added dynamically then how  would your answer work?

Comment: @j08691 - that didn't work either, but I don't think the delegate and it's parameters is the issue. That's what I've been instructed to use. It's most likely the created function that's not setup correctly but not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the delegate function is firing? If you set up a jsFiddle with more of your code, this would be much easier to resolve.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=GvH4Qx5Vgn

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just needing to move  "});//end of add favorites" to the bottom after the delegate function executed. It was executing before the stars were added to the page the way I had it.